# Subreport creating extra blank page

Tags: crystal-reports

My last subreport is creating a blank page at the end of the report. How do I suppress it?

[image: Blank page]

Design screen:

[image: Design screen]

Comment: Can you show us the design view for your RAA Adjustments subreport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your RA Adjustments subreport is extending *just* slightly into the last page. First make sure *New Page After* isn't activated for say, the subreport's group footer. If that's not the case, it's up to you to try and rearrange things within the subreport.

Without a screenshot of the subreport's design view, I can't say exactly how to fix it. But look for ways to shorten it in a way that makes sense for the data you're presenting. Maybe tighten up the blank spaces between sections, make better use of the horizontal space, etc.

If you're still having trouble, upload a screencap of the subreport's design. I can better diagnose the issue if I can see the internals.